# Change content type for static storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

i created a static web app with the a azure storage (see 
https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/azure-storage-static-web-hosting-public-preview/). I uploaded some files without a extension. How can i change the content-type or mime-type for this files?

Thanks

EDIT: I found a solution. You can change over the REST API not via UI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties

Comment: did you tried changing the type using storage explorer?

Comment: @MartinBrandl...IMHO, you should elaborate your comment and post that as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the content-type using the free [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). Just right click on your blob, select properties and change the desired property:

[image]